# gulp-less not creating output css

Tags: less, gulp, gulp-less

I've been struggling with this for a few hours now. I have the following in my gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  gulp.src('C:\\TeamCity\\buildAgent\\work\\5003e8de5901599\\dev\\Content\\css\\less\\dealer-landing.less')
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('C:\\TeamCity\\buildAgent\\work\\5003e8de5901599\\dev\\Content\\css'));
});
```

I run 'gulp styles' which completes with no errors, but the .css is never created. I tried simply commenting out the middle line as seen below and that works as expected; the less file gets copied to the dest directory:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  gulp.src('C:\\TeamCity\\buildAgent\\work\\5003e8de5901599\\dev\\Content\\css\\less\\dealer-landing.less')
    //.pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('C:\\TeamCity\\buildAgent\\work\\5003e8de5901599\\dev\\Content\\css'));
});
```

Any idea why gulp-less doesn't generate the css? If I use just less, the file is generated correctly.

Comment: have you defined `var less = require('gulp-less');`?

Comment: Can you show more of your gulp file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I experienced this due to an undefined class in my less file.

I discovered the undefined class through logging.

Gulp may not throw errors unless you explicitly log them. To log, require `gulp-util` in your gulpfile:

`var util = require('gulp-util');`

And then add logging:

`.pipe(less().on('error', util.log)),`

Run `gulp style` to see the error (possibly an undefined class).

Fix it and your `style` task should generate the css.